# Publish Apk to playstore in beta version

Tags: android, apk, publish, beta

I have an Android App on playstore. Now I have made so many changes to this app and want to update my app. I know simple update is easy but the thing I want is that to publish the new version in beta by keeping the old version remains same. In simple word, I want to publish a new build with beta version that it don't effect the older version?

Note: Old version is not in beta.

Answer (score 2):

Releasing app update to beta channel (open testing) doesn't remove the production release. The beta update will become available as an update to testers only, everyone else will have access to the production release.
For more on releases and roll-outs. [Read more here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859348?hl=en)

Comment: Whats the process to add beta channel?